# Deduce unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, c++20

I am writing a filter util for a class, and stumbled accross this issue, where C++ is not able to deduce the template arg to a templated function:

```cpp
template <class T>
bool is_even(T value) {
    return value % 2 == 0;
}

template <class T>
struct Foo {
    T value;
    template <class Func>
    bool filter(Func func) {
        return func(value);
    }
};


int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
    // works
    foo.filter(is_even<int>);
    // doesnt work, is this possible?
    foo.filter(is_even);
}
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/963MPzfxK)

Is it possible to edit `Foo` such that `foo.filter(is_even)` works?

Comment: No.  You could pass `is_even<int>` or `is_even<char>` or `is_even<long>` to your `filter` function, and the compiler is not going to guess which one you wanted.  The C++ compiler is also not going to try to instantiate every imaginable template argument to `is_even` to see if only exactly one instantiation will work. You would have to make `is_even` a function for `foo.filter(is_even);` to work.

Comment: You cannot do `foo.filter(is_even);`, `is_even` is not a function, it is a template which can produce a function. The possible parameters for a function are: **any instances** (except raw arrays), **references to instance**, **reference to function**, so exclude **functions**, **types**, **templates**,.... Notice that functions are excluded but pointers to function are valid (the `is_even<int>` function case is decayed to type  `bool (*)(int)` and is valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would lambdas work for your use case?

```
auto is_even = [](auto value) {
    return value % 2 == 0;
};

template <class T>
struct Foo {
    T value;
    template <class Func>
    bool filter(Func func) {
        return func(value);
    }
};


int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.filter(is_even);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though above answers are perfectly valid, I propose another one for the record.
The idea is to use functors (classes or objects that personify a function), which IMHO, can be easier to manipulate than lambdas or function pointers.

```cpp
// 1- Making the function a functor
template <class T>
class functor_is_even {
   public:
    // a named function is required as operator() cannot be static (no possible syntax to call it, except on an object)
    static bool Run(T value) { return (value % 2) == 0; }
};
// 2- Simple helper function implemented with the functor
template <class T>
bool is_even(T value) {
    return functor_is_even<T>::Run(value);
}

template <class T>
struct Foo {
    T value;
    template <class Func>
    bool filter(Func func) {
        return func(value);
    }
    // 3- New function that can be instanciated with a not instanciated template
    // class
    template <template <typename U> typename Func>
    bool filter2() {
        // 4- instanciate the right functor
        return Func<T>::Run(value);
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
    // works
    foo.filter(is_even<int>);
    // 5- also works
    foo.filter2<functor_is_even>();
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/EKKoxsa8K)

In `foo.filter(is_even<int>);`, `is_even<int>` is a function pointer that has some value. This value can be passed as an argument to `filter` and `T` can be deduced as the appropriate function pointer type.
In `foo.filter(is_even);`, `is_even` is just a template, it has no value that can be passed as a function argument (and it's not a type either).

1. Instead of a plain function, I write a class with a single static function. This class is the functor and its function plays the role of the original `is_even`.
2. If needed I keep the `is_even` function and implement it with the functor
3. In the `Foo` class I had a template member function `filter2` that can be instanciated with a template functor instead of a plain functor or function
4. Inside `filter2` I instanciate the functor with `Foo` template argument
5. I call `filter2` with my functor template as template template argument instead (not as function argument as, as stated above, `is_even` is not a value).

It's more verbous, in this situation, than, for instance, the [lambda version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76755931/deduce-unresolved-overloaded-function-type/76763562#76763562:%7E:text=Would%20lambdas%20work%20for%20your%20use%20case) but knowing this technics of replacing a function by a functor can be really helpful (for instance, when customizing a behaviour, at compile time (implementing a policy)).
Besides, template functor are easier to partially specialize than template function (actually template function cannot be partially specialized, juste overloaded) but it's another subject.

Answer (score 1):

Template argument deduction and implicit conversions don't mix (for the most part). So, if you want to be able to pass `is_even` to the `Foo` constructor, and have it deduced to mean `is_even<T>`, you have to provide a `filter` function that actually has the type of `is_even<T>` as its parameter; template argument deduction will then kick in, and deduce the template argument of `is_even` in order to make its type match the parameter type exactly (remember, no implicit conversions allowed (for the most part)). You can do it like this:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    T value;

    template <class Func>
    bool filter(Func func) {
        return func(value);
    }

    bool filter(bool (*fp)(T)) {
        return filter<decltype(fp)>(fp);  // delegate to the templated `filter`
    }
};
```

This method is very limited. If you changed the signature of `is_even` to `template <class T> bool (const T&)`, then you would again start getting the "unresolved overloaded function type" error, because you would no longer have an exact match between the type expected by `filter` and one of the possible types of an `is_even` instantiation.